# Prevent Bootstrap tooltip from hiding panel bottom border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**[Click for code sample](http://www.bootply.com/UCpG6OlM85)**

**Problem:**

I have a Bootstrap panel that contains a list group. The panel's bottom border is disappearing if I add a tooltip to the last list group item.

**Solution attempts:**

I suspect one of two issues may be causing this:

1. The panel's height is decreasing when the tooltip appears.
2. The list group item's bottom border is covering up the panel's bottom border.

I started to suspect #2 because of the following in the bootstrap css:

```
.panel>.list-group:last-child .list-group-item:last-child {
    border-bottom:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px
}
```

Because the tooltip adds another element to the list group, the list group item is no longer the last child, so this rule ceases to apply. However, after changing `.list-group-item:last-child` to `.list-group-item:last-of-type` which would effectively ignore the tooltip, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `container` option on the `tooltip()`. This will append the popover to the parent `row` and not impact the style of `list-group`..

```
$('.list-group-item').tooltip({container:'.row'})
```

http://www.bootply.com/WpRFe2EyaM